# Limit the zoom and center on a fixed zone

Tags: python, zoom, static

I would like to create a folium map centered on one location and prevent users from moving outside the zone.

We can define a min_zoom, so that the user can not zoom out for ever.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

point_coordinates = (2.3546, 48.8517) 
point = Point(point_coordinates)
m = folium.Map(location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]], min_zoom=9)
folium.Marker(
    location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]],
    icon=folium.Icon(color='blue'),
    popup="Point d'intérêt"
).add_to(m)
m
```

That is good. Now, my question is: how can I create a bbox and the user can not go outside the rectangle?